# macOS cannot access custom .local domain

Tags: macos, dns

I have a custom DNS server using Adguard Home. Router is configured to use Adguard Home as the DNS server and a lot of `.local` domain names are defined there. Eg. `media.local`.

All my Windows, Android, and ChromeOS devices can access the `media.local` domains except for two of my MacOS devices. If I use anything but `.local` like `media.dev`, then it would work with macOS.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your Mac computer's DNS settings?

Comment: What version of macOS?

Answer (score 1):

`.local` is a special-use domain reserved for the IETF ZeroConf standard (Zero Configuration Networking; what Apple calls "Bonjour"), so it is a conflict to use it for unicast DNS on a private network. The built-in DNS resolvers in Apple OSes (macOS, i[Phone]OS, iPadOS, etc.) only expect to use mDNS (multicast DNS, part of ZeroConf) to resolve those names.

The domain `home.arpa` has been reserved for when you need a non-unique private domain for home use. Or you could use `.test`.

Comment: Why did `media.dev` work then? According to the original poster.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 .dev is not a special-use domain.

Comment: .dev is a [generic top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dev), meaning that anyone who wants to can register a domain under it and use it for whatever they want on the public Internet. media.dev is not currently registered, but if someone registers it your media.dev stuff will conflict with it. [home.arpa is reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special-use_domain_name), so if you use it, you're guaranteed not to conflict with any external usage. .internal has also [been proposed for similar purposes](https://www.theregister.com/2024/01/29/icann_internal_tld/).